# How do I control the duration of the audio recording that is recorded by the record-audio crate?

Tags: rust, audio-recording

I have written a code that records audio using a library
`record-audio = "0.1.1"`.
The recording works fine, but how do I stop the recording and save it to a file?

```
use record_audio::audio_clip::{AudioClip as ac, AudioClip};

fn main() {
    record_audio()
}
fn record_audio() {
    match ac::record(None) {
        Ok(clip) => {
            println!("Successfully recorded!");

            match clip.export(format!("{}", "record.wav").as_str()) {
                Ok(_) => {
                    println!("Successfully saved as ");
                }
                Err(err) => println!("Error {}", err),
            }
        }
        Err(err) => println!("Error {}", err),
    }
}
```

Comment: The crate you're using does not support that other than pressing `Ctrl-C` on the commandline you're running the executable from.

Comment: @cafce25 You mean that the recording cannot be stopped in the same library.
But do you have an extraordinary way to stop the recording, like stopping by a thread or something?

Comment: Sounds a little like you're trying to use a hammer to drive in a screw, sure there might be a way but you probably should look into another crate instead [alsa](https://crates.io/crates/alsa) if you're on linux, I'm certain there is something similar for windows. Or look on https://areweaudioyet.com/ for something else.